# Convert all object values to lowercase with lodash

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, lodash

I have an object:

```
z = {x: 'HHjjhjhHHHhjh', y: 'YYYYY', c: 'ssss'}
```

I need to convert all values to lowercase

```
z = {x: 'hhjjhjhhhhhjh', y: 'yyyyy', c: 'ssss'}
```

How to do this in one time, maybe with lodash? for now I am doing:

```
z.x = z.x.toLowerCase()
z.y = z.y.toLowerCase()
z.c = z.c.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: Simply iterate over the properties of the object. If you don't know how, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196 .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using lodash, you can call [mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) to map the object values, and you can use [method()](https://lodash.com/docs#method) to create the iteratee:

```
_.mapValues(z, _.method('toLowerCase'));
```

Comment: If your object has non-strings values it will remove them. its best to check type `_.mapValues(objs, function(s){
  return _.isString(s) ? s.toLowerCase() : s;
});` **Source:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510712/lowercase-of-object-value-in-array-with-underscore-js

Answer (score 7):

A lot of the stuff you'd use Lodash for you can do quite easily in ES6/ES2015. Eg, in this case you could:

```
var z = { x: 'HHjjhjhHHHhjh', y: 'YYYYY', c: 'ssss' };
var y = Object.keys(z).reduce((n, k) => (n[k] = z[k].toLowerCase(), n), {});

console.log(y);
// { x: 'hhjjhjhhhhhjh', y: 'yyyyy', c: 'ssss' }
```

Pretty neat, eh?

Comment: Browser support for this is ok but not great. YMMV.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript, you can iterate through the object's keys using a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop:

```js
var z = {x: 'HHjjhjhHHHhjh', y: 'YYYYY', c: 'ssss'};

for(var i in z) {
  z[i]= z[i].toLowerCase();
}

console.log(z);
```

I don't know if lodash can improve on that.

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla js:

```
Object.keys(z).forEach(function ( key ) {
    z[key] = z[key].toLowerCase();
});
```

Lodash might have shorter forEach syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution without lodash, you could use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var z = {x: 'HHjjhjhHHHhjh', y: 'YYYYY', c: 'ssss'};

var lowerZ = Object.keys(z).reduce(function(obj, currentKey) {
    obj[currentKey] = z[currentKey].toLowerCase();
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript solution:

```
z = x: 'HHjjhjhHHHhjh', y: 'YYYYY', c: 'ssss'

for key, val of z
    z[key] = val.toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in object) {
    //enter code here...
    const value = object[key].toLowerCase();
    console.log(value);
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)